# Как задать фрейм UIWebView

Tags: objective-c

Как задать фрейм вебвьюхе от навбара? Кладу вебвью, на него сверху навбар или любые другие элементы, например, визуальный эффект с блюром, а вебвью продолжает думать, что верх страницы находится на границе экрана и хэдер страницы уходит под навбар. Как решить? Тот же самый вопрос и с тулбаром внизу экрана.

Comment: Определил, что это редактируется свойством _browserViewMain.frame = CGRectMake();
Вопрос остается только в синтаксисе. Что писать дальше, в скобках?

Comment: Вы добавляете WebView программно или через UIBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, скорее всего, что-то не так с твоим контроллером. Если на view контроллера, который является одним из контроллеров навигейшн контроллера положить `webView`, то все должно работать из коробки.

Сдвинуть сам webView:

```
_browserViewMain.frame = CGRectMake(top, left, bottom, right);
```

где `top` - высота бара, который ты кладешь на `webView`. А вообще лучше посмотри на  `_browserViewMain.scrollView.contentInset` и `self.edgesForExtendedLayout`, и начинай пользоваться `autolayout`.